# Debugging signed react native apk

Tags: react-native

I generated a signed apk but for some reason it does not work as the debug apk does, how can I test it with the debugging feature to view the console and see what issue is there?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to debug the signed apk of react  native then please install and run android studio and show the log of signed apk.

2.and second way is"react-native run-android --variant=release" run this command and install signed apk on your phone and then connect with cli and you able to see the log

Answer (score 0):

run project with this commend" `react-native run-android --variant=release`", release build..

Comment: refer this ``https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging``. if this useful give a thumbs up...

Comment: I installed the apk through "react-native run-android --variant=release" but i still can't access the In-App Developer Menu.

Comment: why you need to debug with signed apk?, you face any prob with production apk?